# Writing text to a file, including spaces

Tags: c++, file, save

I have the following program in C++:

There are two problems with this program.  First of all, if the user makes use of spaces in the text, then the data after the first space is NOT saved.  How can I solve this problem?

Secondly, I want to include a line break between the text appended in one session and another in the text file.  How can I instruct the program to do so?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to get lines of user input at a time. As for the line break between sessions can't you just write a new line to the file after the user is done inputting text. That way the next time you open the file you will start after the line break.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: don't use cin >> text. That will read a string until the first whitespace is found. You probably want to use [cin.getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/).

Second problem: you can simply cout << endl after you write the user's input to the file.

If you don't want the file to have a newline at the end, you need to distinguish between new and existing files. In order to do this, modify your write_to_file function to receive a third argument that tells it whether the file already exists. If it exists, you do cout << endl before writing the user's input to the file.

Comment: Erm... Can you give me an example of how to solve the second problem.  I am not sure I understood correctly :s  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try fwrite instead of fprintf in the write_to_file function. The syntax is a little different though.

fwrite(data, size_t, count, fp);

This will write count number of items of size size_t from data into fp (file pointer)